# Subir fichero por ftp desde un servidor

Tags: php, python, bash, ftp, sftp

Mediante un script, tengo que subir periodicamente un fichero a un servidor WS_FTP desde un Debian.  No puedo instalarle ninguna librería o aplicación al servidor Debian ni tengo permisos, ni el administrador lo hará (ya intenté esto).  La solución debe ser estandar.  WS_FTP es compatible sólo con Windows y sus llaves criptográficas no funcionan con sftp de Debian.
Realicé los siguientes intentos:
Con Bash:

```
# 1
echo "Starting to sftp..."
yes | sftp $USER@$HOST
yes | $PASSWD
yes | put file.txt
yes | bye
#EOF
echo "done"

# 2
sftp ${USER}@${HOST} << END_SCRIPT
quote PASS ${PASSWD}
put file.txt
quit
END_SCRIPT

# 3
sftp ${USER}@${HOST} <<< EOF
${PASSWD} <<< EOF
put file.txt
quit
EOF

# 4
sftp ${USER}@${HOST} | echo -e "\n"
${PASSWD} | echo -e "\n"
put file.txt | echo -e "\n"
quit | echo -e "\n"
```

Con Python, Usando siempre la librería estandar:

```
# 1
import commands

commands.getoutput('user@ftpserver')
commands.getoutput('password')

# 2
import subprocess

command = 'sftp user@ftpserver'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = None, shell = True)

output = process.communicate()

print(output[0])

# 3
import subprocess

subprocess.call('sftp user@ftpserver', shell = True)
subprocess.call(['password'])

output = process.communicate()

print(output[0])

# 4
import sys
import os
import io

oldstdout = sys.stdout
newstdout = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = newstdout
os.system('sftp user@ftpserver\n')
#print stdout
os.system('password\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout = oldstdout

# 5
import ftplib

filename = 'file' 
session = ftplib.FTP(host = host, user = usr, passwd = pwd)
file = open(filename,'rb')
session.storbinary(('STOR ' + filename), file)
file.close()
session.quit()

# 6
import subprocess

subprocess.call(('sftp' + ' ' + usr + '@' + host), shell = True)
subprocess.call(['password'])
output = process.communicate()

# 7
import sys
import os
import io

oldstdout = sys.stdout
newstdout = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = newstdout
os.system(('sftp' + ' ' + usr + '@' + host))
os.system(pwd)

# 8
import commands
import io

newstdout = io.StringIO()

newstdout = commands.getoutput(('sftp' + ' ' + usr + '@' + host))
commands.getoutput(pwd)
```

Incluso lo intenté también con php:

```
<?php
$localFile='localfile';
$remoteFile='remotefile';
$host = "ftpserver";
$port = 22;
$user = "USER";
$pass = "PASS";

$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remoteFile", 'w');
$file = file_get_contents($localFile);
fwrite($stream, $file);
fclose($stream);
?>
```

Nada funcionó.

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Si dices que las llaves criptográficas de sftp no son compatibles con las de WS_FTP, entonces obviamente ni tu programa python ni el bash funcionarán, ya que se limitan a llamar al `sftp `del sistema. En python tal vez puedas investigar la librería paramiko, que es un cliente ssh (y sftp) independiente del que trae debian. Pero en todo caso no veo nada claro cómo podrá hacerse nada con ninguna librería basada en openssh si WS_FTP no usa el estándar, sino su propio cliente. Aunque realmente desconozco WS_FTP y no sé si sigue o no el estándar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, abulafia.  Ya había visto esa librería y pysftp tambíen pero como comenté antes no puedo instalar nada en el servidor Debian.  Sin embargo, con el comando sftp, ingresando la password a mano, pude subir archivos.  Por eso busco estas alternativas.  Tampoco el servidor Debian tiene instaldos sshpass o expect que podría solucionarlo.  Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Si puedes escribir un script python para ejecutarlo en la máquina Debian, es que tienes permiso de escritura en al menos una carpeta. Es todo lo que necesitas para instalar cosas, con tal de que `python -m venv foo` te funcione (necesitas tener un python bastante completo). Si ese comando te funciona, puedo darte una respuesta más detallada de cómo proseguir para instalar paramiko (sin requerir privilegios).

Comment: – abulafia  Puedo probar pero no puedo instalar nada, menos un entorno virtual.  Esto ya lo discutí con el administrador.

Comment: Entiendo. Pues entonces ya sólo se me ocurre probar si lanzando el comando `sftp` con `subprocess.Popen()` y luego usando `.communicate()` para escribir en la entrada estándar del proceso, puedes "meterle" la contraseña. Esto también podría fallar. Tal vez `sftp` hace algo con la entrada estándar para evitarlo. Voy a probar y te cuento

Comment: No, tampoco funciona, pues `ssh/scp/sftp` no leen la contraseña de la entrada estándar. ¿Tienes instalado `expect` en ese Debian? Porque podrías intentar [esto](https://srvfail.com/how-to-provide-ssh-password-inside-a-script-or-oneliner/)

Comment: Ni expect ni sshpass.  El servidor está standard.

Comment: Por favor, podrías editar la pregunta y agregar el mensaje de error? Sin el mensaje de error, es muy complicado.